# Filtering methods of the complex oscilliations

Tags: math, signal-processing

If I have a system of a springs, not one, but for example 3 degree of freedom system of the springs connected in some with each other. I can make a system of differential equations for but it is impossible to solve it in a general way. The question is, are there any papers or methods for filtering such a complex oscilliations, in order to get rid of the oscilliations and get a real signal as much as possible? For example if I connect 3 springs in some way, and push them to start the vibrations, or put some weight on them, and then take the vibrations from each spring, are there any filtering methods to make it easy to determine the weight (in case if some mass is put above) of each mass? I am interested in filtering complex spring like systems.

Comment: Unless the system in non-linear (which it doesn't seem to be), it's very much solvable.

Answer (score 2):

Three springs, six degrees of freedom?  This is a *trivial* solution using finite element methods and numerical integration.  It's a system of six coupled ODEs.  You can apply any form of numerical integration, such as 5th order Runge-Kutta.

I'd recommend doing an eigenvalue analysis of the system first to find out something about its frequency characteristics and normal modes.  I'd also do an FFT of the dynamic forces you apply to the system.  You don't mention any damping, so if you happen to excite your system at a natural frequency that's close to a resonance you might have some interesting behavior.

If the dynamic equation has this general form (sorry, I don't have LaTeX here to make it look nice):

```
Ma + Kx = F
```

where M is the mass matrix (diagonal), a is the acceleration (2nd derivative of displacements w.r.t. time), K is the stiffness matrix, and F is the forcing function.

If you're saying you know the response, you'll have to pre-multiply by the transpose of the response function and try to solve for M.  It's diagonal, so you have a shot at it.

Comment: If the masses are unknown, an eigenvalue analysis won't go very far.

Comment: Masses are unknown.. I have already made a numerical method solution. Now I need to find out how to effectively filter such an oscillations.

Comment: So your objective is to choose the masses to get a desired response?  Do you at least know the forcing functions?  "Filter" might be the wrong word; "tune" could be a better one.  You realize, of course, that you can't completely eliminate all oscillations.  I'm not sure that you have a good handle on the physics here.

Comment: My objective is to understand what are the masses, if I know the oscillations.

Comment: So you want to look at a response for an arbitrary forcing function and back out the masses?  I'd start looking at what are called inverse problems.  I doubt that you can do it, because there's no guarantee that a single mass matrix will uniquely result in the response you see.

Comment: Yes, Having the response of a scales with some force applied I want to estimate the masses correctly. If I have a solution of the differential equation,then may be the inverse solution is possible, but what if I cant?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the springs in such a way that the behavior of the system is approximately linear? (e.g. at least as close to linear as are musical instrument springs/strings?)  Is this behavior consistant over time?  (e.g. the springs don't melt or break.)  If so, LTI (linear time invariant) systems theory might be applicable.  Given enough measurements versus the numbers of degrees of freedom in the LTI system, one might be able to estimate a pole-zero plot of the system response, and go from there.  Or something like a linear predictor might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to solve the resulting system of differential equations as long as you know the masses, etc.

The standard approach is to use a [Laplace Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).  In particular you start with a set of linear differential equations.  Add variables until you have a set of first order linear differential equations.  (So if you have `y''` in your equation, you'd add the equation `z = y'` and replace `y''` with `z'`.)  Rewrite this in the form:

```
v' = Av + w
```

where `v` is a vector of variable, `A` is a matrix, and `w` is a scalar vector.  (An example of something that winds up in `w` is gravity.)

Now apply a Laplace transform to get

```
s L(v) - v(0) = AL(v) + s w
```

Solve it to get

```
L(v) = inv(A - I s)(s w + v(0))
```

where `inv` inverts a matrix and `I` is the identity matrix.  Apply the inverse Laplace transform (if you read up on Laplace transforms you can find tables of inverse of common types of functions - getting a complete list of the functions you actually encounter shouldn't be that hard), and you have your solution.  (Be warned, these computations quickly get very complex.)

Now you have the ability to take a particular setup and solve for the future behavior.  You also have the ability to (if you do things really carefully) figure out how the model responds to a small perturbation in parameters.  But your problem is that you don't know the parameters to use.  *However* you *do* have the ability to measure the positions in the system at repeated times.

If you put this together, what you can do is this.  Measure your position at a number of points.  First estimate all of the initial values of the parameters, and then all of the values a second later.  You can adjust your parameters (using Newton's method) to come close enough to the values a second later.  Take the measurements from 5 seconds later and use that initial estimate as your starting point to refine your calculations for what is happening 5 seconds later.  Repeat with longer intervals to get all of your answers.

Writing and debugging this should take you some time. :-)  I would strongly recommend investigating how much of this Mathematica knows how to do for you already...

Comment: I disagree with the statement "the standard approach".  It's one approach, but it only works for linear systems.  You've neglected other closed form solutions and numerical approaches.

Comment: @duffymo: You're right that I assumed a linear system.  As for standard, it is the approach that I remembered from the course I took 20 years ago.

Comment: It's not that you made a bad recommendation, because Laplace is perfectly acceptable.  But the problem that you don't talk about is that this is really six ODEs.  Applying Laplace transform turns those into 6 coupled algebraic equations that you can solve.  But now you'll have another daunting task: How do you invert the transform to get the final solution?  It's not trivial.

Comment: @duffymo: My memory of solving these problems says that the inverse is not trivial, but not *that* hard.  But as I say, I haven't had to actually do it in 20 years.

Comment: I tried the laplace transform, but when I have to make an inverse transform, it looks that I have to find roots of the equation with the degree of 6. (I mean: a6 x^6 + ... + a1 x + a0)

Comment: Because　we have the system of the differential equation of the second degree.

Comment: The roots are necessary, but how do you incorporate those back into the response?  And how do they give you the masses you said you really need?

Comment: At least if I have a solution in closed form I can do the analysis. Now just numerical methods available. I am just searching for a good methods of mass estimation

Comment: If I know the solution in closed form, then I know the frequencies, of course that depend on masses, and this is something that can be used. Or may be the solution can be used for finding parameters, given some output data. Parameters fitting.